# iOS: Hide navigation bar on UITableView scroll but keep status bar background color

Tags: ios, uitableview, statusbar, navigationbar

I'm trying to hide iOS navigation bar on UITableView scroll but at the same time make sure the status bar has a background color.

I followed https://www.natashatherobot.com/navigation-bar-interactions-ios8/ to hide the status bar:

```
class QuotesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }
}
```

As you can see in the video under Hide Bar On Scroll, the status bar loses its background color (or initially it has no color at all). In my app, bar tint color of the navigation bar is originally set to yellow.

What I'm trying to do is similar to how the Facebook app works on iOS. As you scroll, the navigation bar slides off the screen but the status bar has blue background.

Comment: https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar or https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/HidingNavigationBar maybe?